# Using http query string as a database object node.js/express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Experimenting with node.js / express / mongodb.

I'm using

http://localhost:3000/models/save?model={"name":"blah blah blah"}

to pass a test JSON object to the express route /models/save for saving to the mongodb. Everything works great except the collection.insert statement which returns an "undefined" error.

I think it must be that the parameter extracted from the query string by var model = req.query.model; is not in the correct format. Any ideas?

The code is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/save', function(req, res) {

// Set our internal DB variable
var db = req.db;

var model = req.query.model;
console.log (model);

// Set our collection
var collection = db.get('models');

// Submit to the DB
collection.insert ( model, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        // If it failed, return error
        res.send("There was a problem saving to the database.");
        console.log(doc);
    }
    else {
        console.log ("model saved");
        res.send("OK")
    }
});
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
var model = JSON.parse(req.query.model);
```

instead of the line

```
var model = req.query.model;
```

`JSON.parse` method parses JSON string representation (which in your case is `model` request query parameter) and returns Javascript object which you can then use in your insert process.

I hope it helps some way.